# Single Quote Entry in Bash

Tags: bash, single-quotes

I accidentally entered a single single quote in the commandline of my Debian x86_64 laptop. This starts a > prompt. A second single quote ends the prompt, with the message that the command could not be found.

What is happening here? What commands (if any) are expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add quotes around values to ensure they're treated as strings and not interpreted, e.g.:

```
$ echo 'Hello > foo.txt'
Hello > foo.txt
```

Note that without quotes this would have been a very different command.

Strings can also include newlines:

```
$ echo 'Hello
> World'
Hello
World
```

That's all you're seeing there, a line continuation.

```
$ '
> '
command not found: \n
```

This simply means you entered a newline character as the one and only thing, so it's being interpreted as a command (e.g. like `echo`), and it's not a defined command.